# passing xe:jsonRpcService to csjs class

Tags: xpages

I have a xe:jsonRpcService that I'd like to pass to a csjs class. How is this possible?

The service:

```
<xe:jsonRpcService id="jsonRpcService1" serviceName="rpcServices">
    <xe:this.methods>

        <xe:remoteMethod name="loadEntity"
            script="PersonBean.loadEntity(id);">
            <xe:this.arguments>
                <xe:remoteMethodArg name="id" type="string"></xe:remoteMethodArg>
            </xe:this.arguments>
        </xe:remoteMethod>

    </xe:this.methods>
</xe:jsonRpcService>
```

Call to my class in a output script:

```
formHelper = new FormHeler( rpcServices ) ;
```

The csjs class:

```
function Formhelper( service ) {
   //...
   this.loadEntity = function( id ) {
       //...
       resultObj = service.loadEntity( id ) ;
       //...
   }
}
```

Using rpcServices.loadEntity in the class works. But I'd like to pass it as parameter, so I can use the class with different services.

rpcServices as parameter for the class constructor doesn't work. Is there another way to pass a reference to a service and make it available in the class?

Answer (score 0):

`rpcServices` is a server-side collection of REST service endpoints (the `this.methods`). You can't pass that collection to CSJS, you can only pass the result of *one of the endpoints*.

Think of it as being like trying to pass a SSJS Script Library into a CSJS function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's Paul. Got it to work by passing the service name to the class. Then I use eval to call the rpc method:

```
var serviceName = "rpcServices" ;
formHelper = new FormHelper( serviceName ) ;

function FormHelper( serviceName ) {
    this.serviceName = serviceName ;

    //...
    this.loadEntity = function( id ) {
        var rpcResultObj = eval( this.serviceName + ".loadEntity( \"" + id + "\" )" ) ;
    }
    //...
}
```

Now I can use my FormHelper methods with different services.